# Error: Unknown character set: 'ascii'

Tags: mariadb, character-set

When trying to import a database from a .mysql file, I get an error:

```
ERROR 1115 (42000) at line 24: Unknown character set: 'ascii'
```

The part the error occurs at is from columns using ASCII:

```sql
`column` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL
```

I checked in /usr/share/mariadb/charsets/, and ascii.xml is there. ASCII is listed in the Index.xml as well. However, when looking at the database it's not:

```
MariaDB [db]> show character set;
+---------+------------------+---------------------+--------+
| Charset | Description      | Default collation   | Maxlen |
+---------+------------------+---------------------+--------+
| big5    |                  | big5_chinese_ci     |      2 |
| latin1  |                  | latin1_swedish_ci   |      1 |
| latin2  |                  | latin2_general_ci   |      1 |
| ujis    |                  | ujis_japanese_ci    |      3 |
| sjis    |                  | sjis_japanese_ci    |      2 |
| tis620  |                  | tis620_thai_ci      |      1 |
| euckr   |                  | euckr_korean_ci     |      2 |
| gb2312  |                  | gb2312_chinese_ci   |      2 |
| cp1250  |                  | cp1250_general_ci   |      1 |
| gbk     |                  | gbk_chinese_ci      |      2 |
| utf8    |                  | utf8_general_ci     |      3 |
| ucs2    |                  | ucs2_general_ci     |      2 |
| utf8mb4 | UTF-8 Unicode    | utf8mb4_general_ci  |      4 |
| utf16   | UTF-16 Unicode   | utf16_general_ci    |      4 |
| utf16le | UTF-16LE Unicode | utf16le_general_ci  |      4 |
| utf32   | UTF-32 Unicode   | utf32_general_ci    |      4 |
| binary  |                  | binary              |      1 |
| cp932   |                  | cp932_japanese_ci   |      2 |
| eucjpms |                  | eucjpms_japanese_ci |      3 |
+---------+------------------+---------------------+--------+
19 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

At this point, I don't know what's wrong or how to get the ASCII character set detected and working.

I am using [wodby/mariadb](https://github.com/wodby/mariadb) with tag `MARIADB_TAG=10.5-3.9.5`.

Comment: I suggest using a different docker file for MariaDB.

Comment: replace `ascii` with `binary` as a guess.

Comment: Isn't utf8 a superset of ASCII?

Comment: I'd rather not change the mysql file. It's exported from Drupal, and Drupal [decided](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1923406) to encode some columns with ASCII instead of UTF-8. I need to be able to work with Drupal database and backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had the following in my docker-compose.yml:

```yml
command: >-
  mysqld
    --character-sets-dir='/usr/share/mariadb/charsets'
    --character-set-client-handshake=FALSE
```

This was wrong, as the directory was actually `/usr/share/mysql/charsets`.